# Как посмотреть структуру документа(справочник по структуре документа)?

Tags: vba, libre-office

Как просмотреть структуру документа `libreoffice` `writer`, наподобие `DOM` в `JavaScript`? Чтобы, к примеру, знать как достать таблицу.
И, кто знает, посоветуйте справочник по объектам документа. Есть ли такой, чтобы не рыскать по интернету с вопросом как взять значение из 3ей ячейки таблицы, а потом с вопросом как получить название восьмого рисунка

Comment: Книги Эндрю Питоньяка в помощь

Comment: @slippyk, спасибо большое! Можете написать это в ответ, я отмечу решенным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Книги и статью Эндрю Питоньяка по макросам и в целом по OpenOffice. Больше ничего интересного на русском не встречал.